# Screenly OSE starting in another instance of terminal

Tags: boot-issues, operating-systems

I have been trying to get Screenly OSE up and running.

Everything works really well, but I have a problem.  After the Pi is booted, it starts in the terminal.  On the other hand, if I switch the instance of the terminal to another by pressing F2, Screenly starts up and runs as it should.

It's only running Screenly by pressing F2, I have no clue why.
I want it to start automatically every time I boot the Pi.

Is there anyone out there who has had this problem, or can help me out in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The author of Screenly OSE here.

That's very strange. My best guess would be that something is wrong with the SD card and/or something went wrong during the installation/flashing.

Firstly, are you running on Raspbian Jessie or Wheezy? If Jessie, start over using the latest disk image.

If you're using Jessie, I would suggest that you run the upgrade and try installing the latest developer version to see if that solves the issue.

You can do this by running:

`$ bash <(curl -sL https://www.screenly.io/install-ose.sh)`

Comment: tried with difference sd cards, and I am using this image from github
https://github.com/wireload/screenly-ose/releases/download/v0.9.1/2016-12-01-Screenly_OSE_4GB.zip . And updating it didn't fix it.

Comment: Very strange. The only thing I can think of is that the clock is off (by a lot). What do you get from `date`?